# Removing rows from a dataframe, if the observation for a specific variable is numeric

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, numpy

[data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REbmz.png) I have a large data frame with over 20000 observations, I have a variable called “station” and I need to remove all rows that only have numbers as the s station name.
The only code that has worked so far is :
Df[‘station’][~df[‘station’].str.isnumeric()

However this only creates a data frame with one variable

Comment: please add your dataframe example values and expected result. And why is numpy a tag instead of Pandas?

Comment: I have added the dataframe example values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an extre column with `.str.isnumeric()` to be used later on as a filter:

```
df['filter'] = df['station'].str.isnumeric()
df_filtered = df[df['filter'] != False]#.drop(columns=['filter']
```

This should return all rows that are not only numbers for the column `station`. After that, you can remove the hash if you wish to drop the `filter` column to mantain you original structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so,

```
df_filtered = df[df['station'].str.isnumeric()==False]
```

You wouldn't have to do set operations on your dataframe if you use this.
The internal statements are ultimately a Boolean logic filter that is being applied on the dataframe.